# Mule Illegal character in query

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm trying to acess a webservice with mule,but i'm gettint the following error:

```
 Illegal character in query at index 46: http://localhost:8080/bpo/organization?filter={"name":"organization"}
```

The component i'm using is :

```
<http:request config-ref="RestHEARTBPO" path="organization?filter={&quot;name&quot;:&quot;#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.organization]&quot;}" method="GET" doc:name="Busca Organization no RestHeart">
```

What really bothers me is that i was using 3.7 and an older version of Anypoint studio, today i upgraded and it stoped working.

I have no ideia why its returning this error.

```
ERROR 2016-06-16 16:56:12,645 [[bpo-digesto].BpoListener8081.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Error sending HTTP request.
Payload               : org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream@4ff27c18
Element               : /TrataEventosDaDigesto/processors/2 @ bpo-digesto:salva-movimentacoes-e-envia-para-elaw.xml:44 (Busca Organization no RestHeart)
Element XML           : <http:request config-ref="RestHEARTBPO" path="organization?filter={"name":"#[message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.organization]"}" method="GET" doc:name="Busca Organization no RestHeart"></http:request>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 46: http://localhost:8080/bpo/organization?filter={"name":"organization"}
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3111)
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3053)
    at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.NameResolvingRequestBuilder.<init>(NameResolvingRequestBuilder.java:42)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.DirectNameResolvingRequestBuilder.<init>(DirectNameResolvingRequestBuilder.java:25)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.grizzly.EEGrizzlyHttpClient.doCreateRequestBuilder(EEGrizzlyHttpClient.java:87)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.grizzly.EEGrizzlyHttpClient.createRequestBuilder(EEGrizzlyHttpClient.java:77)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.createGrizzlyRequest(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:348)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.grizzly.GrizzlyHttpClient.send(GrizzlyHttpClient.java:237)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.http.request.grizzly.EEGrizzlyHttpClient.send(EEGrizzlyHttpClient.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.innerProcess(DefaultHttpRequester.java:326)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.request.DefaultHttpRequester.processBlocking(DefaultHttpRequester.java:217)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.process(AbstractNonBlockingMessageProcessor.java:43)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.process(AsyncInterceptingMessageProcessor.java:102)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.construct.DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.process(DynamicPipelineMessageProcessor.java:55)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.interceptor.AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.processBlocking(AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor.java:58)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.process(AbstractFilteringMessageProcessor.java:52)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:98)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.processBlocking(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:56)
    at org.mule.processor.AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.process(AbstractRequestResponseMessageProcessor.java:47)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
    at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:108)
    at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
    at org.mule.construct.AbstractPipeline$3.process(AbstractPipeline.java:232)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.routeEvent(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:73)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:72)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase$1.process(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:59)
    at org.mule.execution.ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.execute(ExecuteCallbackInterceptor.java:16)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.CommitTransactionInterceptor.execute(CommitTransactionInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:30)
    at org.mule.execution.HandleExceptionInterceptor.execute(HandleExceptionInterceptor.java:14)
    at org.mule.execution.BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.execute(BeginAndResolveTransactionInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.mule.execution.ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.execute(ResolvePreviousTransactionInterceptor.java:44)
    at org.mule.execution.SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.execute(SuspendXaTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.mule.execution.ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.execute(ValidateTransactionalStateInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.execute(IsolateCurrentTransactionInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.ExternalTransactionInterceptor.execute(ExternalTransactionInterceptor.java:48)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:28)
    at org.mule.execution.RethrowExceptionInterceptor.execute(RethrowExceptionInterceptor.java:13)
    at org.mule.execution.TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.execute(TransactionalErrorHandlingExecutionTemplate.java:110)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:58)
    at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:35)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:69)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:186)
    at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:57)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at com.mulesoft.gateway.http.phases.GatewayValidationPhase.runPhase(GatewayValidationPhase.java:93)
    at com.mulesoft.gateway.http.phases.GatewayValidationPhase.runPhase(GatewayValidationPhase.java:49)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccessfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65)
    at org.mule.modules.cors.CorsPhase.runPhase(CorsPhase.java:113)
    at org.mule.modules.cors.CorsPhase.runPhase(CorsPhase.java:40)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114)
    at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41)
    at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:133)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:83)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30)
    at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try URL encoding your parameters -

```
filter=
#[java.net.UrlEncoder.encode('{"name":"' + message.inboundProperties.'http.uri.params'.organization + '"}',"UTF-8")]
```

Answer (score 0):

The curly brace is the first character in your URI that causes the URL syntax issue. I'm not sure why things worked before but URI syntax is defined here [RFC-3986][1] - Section 2.

The curly braces can be percent encoded e.g. %20 is a space.

Left curly brace = %7B and right curly brace = %7D

Try this in your mule config...

```
http://localhost:8080/bpo/organization?filter=%7B"name":"organization"%7D
```

Try that and +1 Vote my answer if it works or comment with a notification.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986